# Custom fonts with CKeditor and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

In my Rails 4.2 app,I am trying to add new fonts to the CKeditor Toolbar, what I did is the following :

As the [documentation](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor#customize-ckeditor) says to customize ckeditor I added 2 files :

```
app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js

app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/contents.css
```

in te config.js I have this code :

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {

    config.contentsCss = 'contents.css';

    config.font_names = 'Open Sans;' + config.font_names;

    config.toolbar = [
      ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize']
    ];
 }
```

in the contents.css I have this code :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v10/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3T8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff) format('woff');
}
```

Here the 'Open Sans' is added to the fonts in the toolbar's drop-down, but when i try to apply the 'Open Sans' font to a text it doesn't work !

For now I get this error in the firebug console :

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found  - http://members.lvh.me:3000/posts/assets/contents.css"
```

I tried to change the above : `config.contentsCss = 'contents.css';` to `config.contentsCss = '/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/contents.css';` but it still shows the same 404 Not Found error !!

Also I think even if I fix that it will still don't apply the font ! Is here anyone who know the solution ?

**Update :**

I replaced the `config.contentsCss = 'contents.css';` with `config.contentsCss =  '/assets/ckeditor/contents.css';` and the error disappear, but when I try to apply the font to a text, there is no change !

Answer (score 1):

After a full day of research I finally found a solution which work well for my need, I hope this can help someone in the same situation (so you don't have to struggle like I did )

just add the following code to your app/assets/javascripts/ckeditor/config.js

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function(config) {
   // .....
   // .....
  // an array of fonts from "google fonts", I listed 3 fonts here
  myFonts = ['Architects Daughter', 'Open Sans', 'Dancing Script'];

  config.font_names = 'sans serif';

  for(var i = 0; i<myFonts.length; i++){
     config.font_names = config.font_names+';'+myFonts[i];
     myFonts[i] = 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family='+myFonts[i].replace(' ','+');

     //assuming you use jquery
     $("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' href='"+ myFonts[i] +"'>");
  }
}
```

just to mention that this solution is founded here : http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-3.x/CKE-and-Google-Fonts-Api, thanks to 'naveenram'